# Error in Reading nested dictionaries C

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

I want to read nested dictionaries in c#.
declared as follow:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict2 = 
    new Dictionary<string, double>();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> dict1 = 
    new Dictionary<string,  Dictionary<string, double>>();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>> globalDict = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>>();
```

I used the following code to read it:

```
foreach (var key3 in globalDict.Keys)
{
    foreach (var key2 in globalDict[key3].Keys)
    {
        foreach (var key1 in globalDict[key2].Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(globalDict[key3][key2][key1]);
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me the following error :

> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'

in this line:

```
foreach (var key1 in globalDict [key2].Keys)
```

Any suggestions about the method I used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to first access `globalDict[key3]`, as you are already one `Dictionary` deep:

```
foreach (var key3 in globalDict.Keys)
{
     foreach (var key2 in globalDict[key3].Keys)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Jours {0}", key2);

         foreach (var key1 in globalDict[key3][key2].Keys) // here
         {
              Console.WriteLine(globalDict[key3][key2][key1]);
         }
     }
}
```